# Query for select when variable is in a third table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

translation of table names (medicamento = medicine, evolucion= evolution of patient, paciente= patient)

1st table medicamento with columns (id, monodroga, dosis, evolucion_id(fk))

2nd table evolucion with columns (id, description, paciente_id(fk))

3rd table paciente with columns (id, name, etc)

each medicamento belongs to one evolucion

one evolucion has 1 or 0 medicamento

each evolucion belongs to one paciente

one paciente has one or many evolucion

1st table is related with 2nd but has no relation with the third one
my variable is id (of table paciente)

how can a select all the medicamento where the evolucion.paciente_id = id (of table paciente)

i need to select all the medicamento that corresponds to each evolucion of a selected paciente

I am using postgres

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rephrase this: "_1st table is related with 2nd but has no relation with the third one my variable is id (of table paciente)_"

Comment: Sample data, expected results missing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want a list of medicamentos, then make `medicamento` the `LEFT` table. This means you are fetching ALL medicamentos under the pacient-ID filter (pac.id = 123). For each medicamento you can also fetch corresponding `evolucion` and `paciente` details if you wish. You can also apply corresponding `GROUP BY` conditions, a task which depends on your data in the tables (which you can provide to us if you wish).

```
SELECT 
    med.monodroga,
    med.dosis,
    evo.description,
    pac.name
FROM medicamento AS med 
LEFT JOIN evolucion AS evo ON evo.id = med.evolucion_id 
LEFT JOIN paciente AS pac ON pac.id = evo.paciente_id 
WHERE pac.id = 123;
```